# How can i receive json data on PHP file?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, json

I am new in Xamarin and C# ,I want from my app to insert Books name and author to MySql database ,so I made class with name BooksInsert.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace NewTest.Model
{
    class BooksInsert
    {
        public string book_name { get; set; }
        public string book_auther { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then another class with name WebHelper.cs for GET and POST :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace NewTest.Model
{
    class WebHelper
    {
        public string Post(Uri url, string value)
        {
            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";

            try
            {
                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
                }
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                return responseString;
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public string Get(Uri url)
        {
            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";

            try
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                return responseString;
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

in the adding page NewBookPage.xaml I have this contents :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="NewTest.NewBookPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="b_name" Placeholder="Name of Book"/>
            <Entry x:Name="b_auther" Placeholder="auther of Book"/>
            <Button Text="Save"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and NewBookPage.xaml.cs :

```
using NewTest.Model;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;


namespace NewTest
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewBookPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewBookPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebHelper webHelper = new WebHelper();

            BooksInsert item = new BooksInsert();
            item.book_name= b_name.Text;
            item.book_auther = b_auther.Text;


            string request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

            Uri url = new Uri(string.Format("localhost/API/insert.php"));

            string response = webHelper.Post(url, request);

            if (response != null)
            {
                //Handle your reponse here
            }
            else
            {
                //No Response from the server

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i don't know how to continue send json file to insert.php file and in insert.php how can i receive json data ,can any one help me?

Comment: You don't need to send JSON *files* to the PHP scripts. If those PHP scripts receive the payload as JSON, you just need to encode you payload as such. I seems you are already doing it here: `string request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);` in `NewBookPage.xaml.cs`. Have you tested your program? Could you provide further data, such as the request response and errors? Do you know the `insert.php` API?

Comment: @Andre i tested it ,it saied that the uri format not supported ,then how can i insert the data to MySql database

Comment: Is this PHP script running in a local webserver? Have you tried to put `http://` in front of the URL, so it turns `http://localhost/API/insert.php`? Also, I would check in which port it is running, generally, port `80`.

Comment: There is no problim with http:// url but now i just need how to riciev data on insert.php file

Comment: @AndreRavazzi I checked it in http:// ,new row inserted in data base but without data ,insert.php ddn't receive data from app ,how can i receive data in insert.php

Answer (score 0):

Your `Post` method in `WebHelper.cs` is expecting an `Uri` entity as the first argument to be passed to `HttpWebRequest.Create`. But as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netcore-3.1) states, it seems to expect a `string` as parameter, not an `Uri` class. Besides `HttpWebRequest` is obsolete and should not be used for new developments. MS states you should use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

Try using `WebRequest.Create` instead as in this tutorial from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/API/insert.php");
```

If you change the `Post` method signature, then you don't need to use the `Uri` class in `NewBookPage.xaml.cs`, just send the URI as string to `Post`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is correct ,but i tried simple way to insert data's to MySql database ,I just did this NewBookPage.xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="NewTest.NewBookPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="b_name" Placeholder="Name of Book"/>
            <Entry x:Name="b_auther" Placeholder="auther of Book"/>
            <Button Text="Save"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            <WebView x:Name="webView"
                WidthRequest="1000"
                HeightRequest="500"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

NewBookPage.xaml.cs :

```
using NewTest.Model;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;


namespace NewTest
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewBookPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewBookPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webView.Source = " https://Mywebsite/insert.php?bn=" + b_name.Text + "&ba=" + b_auther.Text;   
        }
    }
}
```

insert.php

```
$bname=$_GET['bn'];
$bauthor=$_GET['ba'];
$query = "INSERT INTO books  VALUES ('','$bname','$bauthor')";
mysqli_query($berikane,$query);
```

data inserted correctly ,how is this solution possible?

Comment: Your `insert.php` does not receive JSON, but URL params. You should acknowledge the API of your backend before building its consumers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have sent Post data from Xamarin to  PHP file and received it as post value :

```
 private  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var values = new NameValueCollection();
                values["book_name"] = b_name.Text;
                values["book_auther"] = b_auther.Text;

                var response = client.UploadValues("https://MyWeb/insert.php", values);

                var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);

                if (response != null)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Success" ,"Data Inserted Successfully" ,"OK");
                }
            }

        }
```